# CSS3 : show border on focus to the both textbox

Tags: html, css

I have a 2 text boxes. when I focus on 1st textbox. I get border but when I focus on 2nd textbox I don't get `border-top`. I have given `border-top:none` to the 2nd textbox as 1st textbox's border-bottom mixes with the 2nd textbox border-top.

I want to solve this issue using only CSS3.

```css
.form-control{
  padding:6px 12px;
  border:thin black solid;
}

.form-control:focus{
border:thin green solid;
}

.add_url .form-control{
  padding:6px 12px;
  border:thin black solid;
  border-top:none;
}

.add_url .form-control:focus{
border:thin green solid;
border-top:none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="enter url 1">
<div class="add_url">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="enter url 2">
</div>
```

PS : When I focus on any of the text box , I should get border to be green to all around the textbox.

Any help would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: Try to add margin for textbox.

Comment: i can't it should be look like there is no more than 1 border between 2 textbox

Comment: Try to change the order of border property like, border: thin solid black.

Comment: that doesn't matter.

Comment: @Rishi  Bro... Check The Snippet..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't hide the 2nd box border, just position it under the 1st. When one of the boxes is focused use the `outline` to highlight it, and bring it to the top, so it won't be under the other box:

```css
.form-control {
  position: relative;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: thin black solid;
}

.form-control:focus {
  border: thin green solid;
}

.add_url .form-control {
  top: -1px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: thin black solid;
}

.form-control:focus {
  outline: 1px green solid;
  outline-offset: -1px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="enter url 1">
<div class="add_url">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="enter url 2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this is the best way :

**HTML :**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="enter url 1">
<div class="add_url">
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter url 2">
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
input {
        padding:6px 12px;
        border:2px black solid;
        outline: 0;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 0;
    }

    input:focus{
        border:2px green solid;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .add_url input { margin-top: -2px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example:** Create an `form-control:focus` in css and set the border as `green` and `outline:none` and `z-index:1`

```css
.form-control{
  padding:6px 12px;
  border:thin black solid;
}


.form-control:focus {
padding:6px 12px;
border:thin green solid;
outline:none;
z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="add_url">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="enter url 1">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="enter url 2">
</div>
```